# Exit from script if SSH prompts for password

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh

I am trying to achieve a scenario where I need to  SSH to ABC server from XYZ server. Public keys will set up already to smooth password less login. Now i just want to exit from script if found that  SSH command prompts for password. It means  public key are not set up.

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 user@ABC <<HERE
----- doing some stuff here----
HERE
```

Ouput-

```
Password:
```

Script resides on XYZ. I am running it from XYZ and trying to SSH ABC. If it prompts for password then exit from script by printing a message.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes
```

according to `man 5 ssh_config`

> BatchMode
>
> ```
>        If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled.
>          In addition, the ServerAliveInterval option will be set to 300
>          seconds by default.  This option is useful in scripts and other
>          batch jobs where no user is present to supply the password, and
>          where it is desirable to detect a broken network swiftly.  The
>          argument must be “yes” or “no”.  The default is “no”.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add `PreferredAuthentications=publickey` option to your connection string:

`ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o ConnectTimeout=10 user@ABC`

The exit code will 255 and you will get this information:

`user@ABC: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`

Comment: I tried to use same but  it did not work for me. I am still getting prompt to provide the password. I would like to exit rather wait whenever my ssh command prompt for password. This is what I need to achieve.

Comment: @VivekPandey it works for me. Which version of SSH do you have installed?

Comment: its' OpenSSH_6.6.1p1. I used it like- "ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o ConnectTimeout=10 user@ABC << HERE ------ do some stuff here on ABC from XYZ-------- HERE. But it still waits on password prompts, do not exit

Comment: I have version 7.4 and 7.8 and it's working. Unfortunately I don't have access to machine with OpenSSH6.6

Comment: Anyway to achieve this for OpenSSH6.6 machine

Answer (score 0):

Add PasswordAuthentication=no to your ssh options

```
$ ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no host
user@host: : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
$ echo $?
255
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work. It may be the duplicate question but answers provided for previous questions did not work here. I am trying to ssh to another server and execute some commands on that server from source server. SSH keys are set up but if these are not there than script will prompt for password. I would like to quit if it prompts for password.